# ReactJS : Using VX library with IE11?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg, sharepoint, internet-explorer-11

I try to create an app with SharePoint Framework width ReatcJS and some svg. I use some element of the VX library (text and responsive) (d3.js for react). They work fine with Firefox but they don't work with Internet Explorer 11.
And I need them to work on Internet Explorer 11. It's the main browser in my company.

I use vx/responsive like this :

```
<ScaleSVG id="root" width={908} height={440}> 
<svg>...</svg>
</ScaleSVG>
```

And vx/text :

```
<Text lineHeight="1em" verticalAnchor="middle" x="205" y="60" id="text2997" width="200" textAnchor="middle" style={{ fontSize: 40, fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: 'normal', lineHeight: '125%', letterSpacing: 0, wordSpacing: 0, fill: '#FFFFFF', fillOpacity: 1, stroke: 'none', fontFamily: 'Sans' }}>My text</Text>
```

How can I do to make them work on IE11 ?

Comment: Any error messages when using the app in IE 11? E.g. something like `ReferenceError 'Symbol' is undefined` or similar messages?

Comment: No, no message event in the web console or in my command pannel.